# Using powershell, how to modify and save a client-side outlook rule, from the client-side?

Tags: powershell, outlook, rules

PS 5.1,
Windows 10,
Outlook o365 desktop client

Hello,

How do I save a rule after I modify it's properties? I am an Outlook o365 user, not an Exchange Admin and I want to modify and save my own existing client-side rules.

At this point, I know how to get rule properties and set some of them, but I haven't figured out how to successfully save the rules. I get the following error from $rules.Save()

"You cannot add another rule because you have exceeded the maximum number of rules for this store."

But, I have not exceeded the maximum number of rules for my store because I can manually create more using the gui. I'm not even trying to create a new rule, but modify properties on existing rules.
The code below should simply disable all the enabled rules, but it does not.

```
cls
#Add Outlook Library
    Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.outlook
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
#Get Your Rules
    $rules = $outlook.session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
#Disable enabled rules
    ForEach($rule in $rules){
        if($rule.enabled -eq $true){
            $rule.Enabled = $false
        }
    }
    $rules.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange server limits the maximum number of rules that can be supported by a store. `Rules.Save` returns an error when this limit is reached.

After you have defined a rule, you should also enable it by setting the `Rule.Enabled` property to `True`, and then save the rule by using `Rules.Save` so that the rule and its enabled state will persist beyond the current session. A rule is only enabled after it has been saved successfully. Note that `Rules.Save` can be an expensive operation in terms of performance on slow connections to Exchange server; you can optionally display a progress dialog box for the user to cancel the operation. Pass `True` to display the progress dialog box, `False` to save rules without showing the progress. A save fails when the user edits the same rule in the `Rules and Alerts Wizard`, or the user cancels the progress dialog box. In such cases, `Rules.Save` will raise an error, and the user will resolve the conflict by responding to the error dialog brought up by the `Rules and Alerts Wizard`.

Answer (score 0):

To save the modified rule, all I needed to do was place either $true or $false as a parameter inside the $rules.save() method. So, $rules.save($true) would show a progress popup window and $false wouldn't.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._rules.save?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__Rules_Save_System_Object_